# git branch is in detached from refs/heads/developer

Tags: git, git-branch, git-rebase

I run the `git checkout <commid-id>` and once the HEAD was in detached state, I made few commits to in the detached state. Then I created the branch called developer so that all the commits that I did when in detached state came inside my `developer` branch.  Now I ran the command `git checkout developer` and then `git rebase master`. I got few conflicting changes and then I closed the terminal.

The next time I opened and ran the `git rebase master` I got the below message

```
It seems that there is already a rebase-apply directory, and
I wonder if you are in the middle of another rebase.  If that is the
case, please try
git rebase (--continue | --abort | --skip)
If that is not the case, please
rm -fr "/Users/pl1/my_project/.git/rebase-apply"
and run me again.  I am stopping in case you still have something
valuable there.
```

I ran the below command
    rm -fr "/Users/pl1/my-project/.git/rebase-apply"

Now when I run the `git branch` command I get the below:

```
*(detached from refs/heads/developer)
  developer
  master
```

I ran the `git rebase master` command once again. Got the below message:

```
Cannot rebase: You have unstaged changes.
Additionally, your index contains uncommitted changes.
Please commit or stash them.
```

Running `git status` command now gives:

```
HEAD detached from refs/heads/developer
Changes to be committed:
(use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

modified:   client/app/filterEnv/filterEnv.directive.js
modified:   client/app/filterEnv/filterEnv.html
modified:   client/app/filterEnv/filterEnv.scss
modified:   client/app/hostsTable/hostsTable.directive.js
modified:   client/app/main/main.html
modified:   client/app/results/results.html
modified:   package.json

Unmerged paths:
(use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
(use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

both modified:   root@remotehost.corp.net
```

I am confused with my current state. How to rebase my developer branch changes to master from here. Is my changes inside the `developer` branch lost now? Please let me know since I am new to running the `git rebase` command.

Comment: Why are you working in the detached head state in the first place?  This is typically done for exploratory reasons.  If you want a branch from `master`, then just create and do your work there.  And also, why are you rebasing on `master`?  On which were you when you entered the detached state?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you never did `git rebase --continue` to continue the rebase after the stop. This is required.